# Prevent spoofing location

Tags: java, android, gps, location

is there a way to prevent spoofing location when the user's device are below 18 API?

i have tried using below code but it's not working when user are :
1. Enable Mock Location in Android Setting and active fake gps 
2. Disable Mock Location in Setting (Without pause/stop fake gps app) -> in this case my app still get fake location.

My Code :

```
if (isGPSEnabled) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
    if (locationManager != null) {
        location = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(location != null){
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18)
                isMock = location.isFromMockProvider();
            else
                isMock = !Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION).equals("0");

            if(!isMock){
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                prefs.setMockProvider(false);
            }else{
                prefs.setMockProvider(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the `enable mock locations` option from settings will not make sense and also even you delete the mocker app from your device, the mock location will be persisted.

Solution : make location request for given provider and **wait until receiving new location**